# Cordova Persist Session on iOS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm having trouble figuring out how to persist a session on an iOS Cordova app.

I'm using Node.js/Express on the backend and Angular on the front-end. My onboarding processes work properly and everything is dandy until the user closes the application. When it is reopened, the user has been logged out.

I understand WHY this is happening, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to prevent it. Can I use local storage to store and retrieve a cookie? If so, what's the preferred method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could use whatever value you want in LocalStorage, as long as you don't get messy with multiple users using the app.. Just check for that value when the app starts and do the magic for user already logged in.

If you want to add more security, perhaps you can save a token in LocalStorage, when the app starts, retrieve that token and compare it against your backend, to check if it's active or not, after that, more coding magic :)

The second option will make the user's workflow a lil bit more slower due to the app request and the server response.

What data should you save? That's up to you, depending on your app, what it needs to 'boot'. If you use a token, you can send the needed data in the server's response.

There should be always something that identifies that user on the server, and not only his username or id, I believe you use something to tell the server that THIS USER is logged in while the app interacts with the server.

Some data about LocalStorage: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html

PS: If you are already using AngularJS, you should check [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) and [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/).

Good luck!